# In R, is there a parsimonious or efficient way to get a regression prediction holding all covariates at their means?

Tags: r, regression

I'm wondering if there is essentially a faster way of getting predictions from a regression model for certain values of the covariates without manually specifying the formulation. For example, if I wanted to get a prediction for a given dependent variable at means of the covariates, I can do something like this:

```
glm(ins ~ retire + age + hstatusg + qhhinc2 + educyear + married + hisp,
    family = binomial, data = dat)
meanRetire <- mean(dat$retire)
meanAge <- mean(dat$age)
meanHStatusG <- mean(dat$hStatusG)
meanQhhinc2 <- mean(dat$qhhinc2)
meanEducyear <- mean(dat$educyear)
meanMarried <- mean(dat$married)
meanYear <- mean(dat$year)

ins_predict <- coef(r_3)[1] + coef(r_3)[2] * meanRetire + coef(r_3)[3] * meanAge +
               coef(r_3)[4] * meanHStatusG + coef(r_3)[5] * meanQhhinc2 +
               coef(r_3)[6] * meanEducyear + coef(r_3)[7] * meanMarried +
               coef(r_3)[7] * meanHisp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh... There is a `predict` function:

```
fit <- glm(ins ~ retire + age + hstatusg + qhhinc2 + educyear + married + hisp,
           family = binomial, data = dat)
newdat <- lapply(dat, mean)    ## column means
lppred <- predict(fit, newdata = newdat)    ## prediction of linear predictor
```

To get predicted response, use:

```
predict(fit, newdata = newdat, type = "response")
```

or (more efficiently from `lppred`):

```
binomial()$linkinv(lppred)
```

Comment: jesus.  That would have saved so much time. Thank you.